# Getting "move_uploaded_file(): failed to open stream: Permission denied" error in Laravel

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5, permission-denied

When my form is submitted I can see file name,size etc but I can't upload it because it keeps saying permission denied. I changed owner of myapp/storage to `www-data:www-data` and did

```
php artisan cache:clear 

chmod -R 777 myapp/storage
```

as suggested here: ['Failed to open stream: Permission denied' error - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel), but it didn't help.

My form is created with `<form> <input>` tags, not with `{{ Form }}` elements, so I'm uploading it with `move_uploaded_file()` and not `Input::file()->move()`.

I took screenshots of error message in browser and terminal with ls -l but I can't post images yet :/

Original form that I want to submit isn't form with action, method...I submit it with ajax, but since that wasn't working I made a small form with just 2 inputs to see what's going on...and it says permission denied

EDIT 2:
error message:

```
    Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

    1/1
    ErrorException in AdminFunkcije.php line 121:
    move_uploaded_file(/slika.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
    in AdminFunkcije.php line 121
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'move_uploaded_file(/slika.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/home/tamara/hexdoo/app/Http/Controllers/AdminFunkcije.php', '121', array('username' => 'lalal', 'size' => '1'))
    at move_uploaded_file('/tmp/phpCLtMt3', '/slika.jpg') in AdminFunkcije.php line 121
    at AdminFunkcije->dodajKategorije2()
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminFunkcije), 'dodajKategorije2'), array()) in Controller.php line 246
    at Controller->callAction('dodajKategorije2', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AdminFunkcije), object(Route), 'dodajKategorije2') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AdminFunkcije), object(Route), object(Request), 'dodajKategorije2') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminFunkcije', 'dodajKategorije2') in Route.php line 198
    at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
    at require_once('/home/tamara/hexdoo/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

PHP

```
    public function dodajKategorije2() {
        if(isset($_POST['username'])) { $username = $_POST['username'];}

        echo count($_FILES)."
". print_r($_FILES);

        if(isset($_FILES['profileImg'])) { 
            $size= intval($_FILES['profileImg']['size'],10);    
           if($size > 10485760) { 
                return "file size: ".$_FILES['profileImg']['size'];
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profileImg']['tmp_name'][0] ,"/slika.jpg");
                return "ok";
            }
         }
         else return "no file ";
    }
```

FORM

`<form id="data" method="POST" action="admin/dodaj_kategorije" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      User Name: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br />
      Profile Image: <input name="profileImg[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>`

Comment: (If you want to add HTML/XML tags to a Stack Overflow question, just wrap it in backticks (`inline code`) or indent four spaces (for a block)).

Comment: "My form is created with <form> <input> tags, not with {{ Form }} elements, so I'm uploading it with move_uploaded_file() and not Input::file()->move()." Doesn't matter. Use `Input::file()->move()`. It works fine with raw HTML forms.

Comment: Do you have the error log, I would like to analyze it

Comment: Can you provide the error text since you can't post the images?

Comment: I've updated question with error text...it should upload that file in public folder,right? which owner should be set for other folders? I changed only storage folder owner and permissions.

Comment: that  **echo print_r($_FILES) **  gave me this:

Array ( [profileImg] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 6zx1y8.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/php6vOcbE ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 90735 ) ) ) 1

Comment: @ceejayoz  That's nice :) It didn't work before because of unknown Input class...I fixed that, now with Input::file()->move 

error text is:
- Unable to create the "/upload" directory - 

and if I leave $destination as '/' it says 
- MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:
in RouteCollection.php line 207
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 142

and I removed [] so only one file is uploaded.

Comment: @AcácioVeitSchneider do you think reason this is happening could be  bad installation? I installed laravel with composer on ubuntu 14, maybe I overlooked something? Before this I was getting error TokenMissmatch exception on POST submit and GET was working fine...I tried to add token in hidden input and then submit it with form but it didn't work, so I just commented line that verifies token in Kernel.php

Could it be this is happening because of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. 
I had www-data:www-data set as owner of folder storage but it kept saying

`unable to create '/upload' directory`

I set destination to 
`'./upload'` **with the dot '.'**

it still says

`file was not uploaded due to an unknown error`

but when I checked (accidentally) public folder file was there...

I don't know why it says it's not uploaded due to error but **it does upload file every time** so for me it works with that dot.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use move function for upload the file to Public folder. Then it will be easier for you to access the file from anywhere in your application.

```
//For access the file
$file = $request->file('image');

//Display File Name

echo 'File Name: '.$file->getClientOriginalName();
  echo '<br>';

  //Display File Extension
  echo 'File Extension: '.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  echo '<br>';

  //Display File Real Path
  echo 'File Real Path: '.$file->getRealPath();
  echo '<br>';

  //Display File Size
  echo 'File Size: '.$file->getSize();
  echo '<br>';

  //Display File Mime Type
  echo 'File Mime Type: '.$file->getMimeType();

  //Move Uploaded File
  $destinationPath = 'uploads';
  $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Above move function will upload the file with its real name(original file name). if you want to customize it you can use a uniqid() function for generate a unique file name,

```
//Move Uploaded File
$up_name = uniqid();
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$file->move($destinationPath, $up_name );
```