# Persistent Permission Denied Error

Tags: laravel

I have seen a few posts on this (and tried the recommended solutions) but they are regarding Laravel 4 - And I am on Laravel 5.

For example;

['Failed to open stream: Permission denied' error - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel)

I get the `Command "dump-autoload" is not defined` error and the reason for that is explained here;

http://laravel.io/forum/12-08-2014-command-dump-autoload-is-not-defined

In the above post, `composer dump-autoload` was suggested. I tried it, and again this morning the same error is back;

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line
74:file_put_contents(/vagrant/source/laravel- excel/storage/
framework/sessions/8338f386fc3de7bdc8d1b6dc7ee6790f71516d98): failed
to open stream: Permission denied`
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is permissions issue on the filesystem. Ensure that the storage folder and all of its subfolders are fully accessible by the user you're using to execute composer.

Comment: Have you changed the folder `storage` permission to 644  or 755 yet? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#configuration

Comment: This could be related to how you edit the files on the server. Which IDE do you use? Do you use some sort of "automatic upload of changed/created files" option? I'm asking because changing or creating a new file, then uploading it to the server "automatically" will usually set that file's permissions to the user with which you _connect_ to the server, and it could be different than the one the webserver operates under.

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov I am using Vagant and Sublime Text 2 to edit my files.. Yes I suppose I am uploading to the server "automatically" in that case.

Comment: Okay, then try to create a new file in your Sublime project, then go to the console on the server and do `ls -la /path/to/new/file.php` - this will show you which user the file belongs to and what its permissions are. Also, the path above has a space in it: `/vagrant/source/laravel- excel/storage/
framework/sessions/` - are you sure that's accurate? This space might be confusing to the script.

Comment: That space was just me using StackOverflow. Sorry. The new file I created has "vagrant" as the user and group. Just like all the others in same directory. The permissions are 644. All the others are 777 (because I've been doing that whenever I get that error)

Comment: I haven't used Vagrant, but if all other dirs have the same user:group set, it's probably the same user that the webserver runs. 4 means reading only, change the permissions of app/storage to `664` **recursively**

Comment: Interestingly, `chmod -R 664 laravel-excel` does not clear the error but `chmod -R 777 laravel-excel` does...

Answer (score 1):

Also, try the above comments and do a

composer self update

Answer (score 0):

You Have to set the permission to Read & Write

In Mac We do this by using

**sudo chmod -R o+w storage**

**Storage** is the name of file U want to change permission
And **currently my terminal is in the same folder where my storage folder is present** therefore I did not specify its address