# Laravel 5 permission denied when writing in log file

Tags: ubuntu, logging, laravel-5

I have Ubuntu and Laravel 5 framework and I see the white screen in the browser.
When I change `storage/logs` directory permissions it helps, but I have to do it every day, due the 'daily' log configuration.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error. By using the following command I could solve it. For some reason, it is not about the log file.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Right here, for me this is the best answer - short and clean.

Comment: Could you please explain why those commands solved the issue? It also worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

The permissions for the `storage` and `vendor` folders should stay at `775`, for obvious security reasons.

However, both your computer and your server Apache need to be able to write in these folders. Ex: when you run commands like `php artisan`, your computer needs to write in the logs file in `storage`.

All you need to do is to give ownership of the folders to Apache :

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /path/to/your/project/vendor
sudo chown www-data:www-data /path/to/your/project/storage
```

Then you need to add your computer (referenced by it's `username`) to the group to which the server Apache belongs. Like so :

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data userName
```

Most frequently, `groupName` is `www-data` but you might want to replace it with your correct group.

Comment: Unfortunattely, your approach wouldn't help. By default Apache creates new files with permissions 644 (-rw-r--r--). It means artisan can't write to the same file whether it belongs to the www-data group or not.

Comment: You are right. I will delete my answer. However, you should consider adding the user to the www-data group and keeping 775, rather than 777 all the folder.  We need a solution that works for production too.

Answer (score 3):

- chmod 777 is in general a security risk extremely risky.
- chmod 775 for the storage folder is fine considering user also
  belongs to web server group.
- with -R its extremely risky since for files an execute permissions is not at all required.
- chmod 664 for files inside storage. chmod 775 for folders inside

Answer (score 1):

In `config/login.php`, check permissions are set:

```
'daily' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
    'days' => 14,
    'permission' => octdec('0666'),
],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

**Short answer:**

`sudo chmod -R 777 vendor storage`
`echo "umask 000" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf`
`sudo service apache2 restart`

**Extensive answer:**

When you launch Laravel 5 framework on Apache server with enabled by default 'daily' option for creating log files, sometimes you would face with forbiddance of writing into logfiles due the file permissions.
Ususally, when you have php project all files belong to `www-data` user, and your current user has no need to write to logfiles.
Regarding the Laravel, two different processes need to write to your logfiles:
1) Apache server (user `www-data`) when you do something in your browser;
2) Php process (your user) when you execute `php artisan something` in command line.

Of course, you can execute sudo -u www-data php artisan your_command (like suggested [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6453) ) each time you want to use artisan, but it is a bit annoying.
First of all you need to give permissions to vendor and storage directories for Apache user.
Most easiest way (but not the best one) is to perform:
`sudo chmod -R 777 vendor storage`

Now, lets see what happens when logfile creates in both cases.

If initially logfile `storage/logs/laravel-2015-mm-dd.log` was created through the error raised by
`php artisan something` command (case 2), log file will have

```
`-rw-rw-r-- your_user:your_user`
```

permissions.
If it was created by your apache server (case 1), which ussually launch under `www-data` user, permissions will look like this:

```
-rw-r-r-- www-data:www-data
```

So, my suggestion is to change permissins for newly created files by apache.
Let's add line `umask 000` to `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

```
echo "umask 000" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Now,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That's it.
Be aware, this solution is applicable for **development environment only**, due the possible secutity risk.

Comment: tbh, you should never want to chmod 777, ever.

Comment: What to do in production environment? For example, on DigitalOcean? What to do for Nginx? For example, on DigitalOcean LEMP?

Comment: Any update on how to accomplish this with a production server?

Comment: This is terrible, terrible advice.  Do NOT follow this.  First off, /etc/resolv.conf has *nothing* to do with file permissions.  If you are crazy, you can set the default umask in /etc/login.defs for a common Linux system using pam_umask.  Another common place to put it is /etc/profile, or even /etc/rc.local.  Still, you should *not* do this.  Security is important, even on a dev system.

Comment: Some of the posters are being rude to you. You brought up a key concept not thought of by other posters in that Artisan and web traffic can be sourced from different users.  This caused huge problems in my case.  My scheduler ran artistan every five minutes...but as root.  So my log file would rotate to root, then when a web request tried to write to the log it crashed the system.  I fixed this by making sure my crontab command for artistan scheduler was executed as the web user...not root.  Thank you!