# Laravel 5 '..failed to open stream: Permission denied' exception when connecting to localhost

Tags: php, macos, permissions, laravel-5

Have set up a project and when trying to connect to the local host I get this error in the console:

> [Wed Aug 12 21:26:46 2015] 127.0.0.1:50079 [500]: / - Uncaught
>   exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file
>   "/CT/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied' in
>   /CT/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87
>       Stack trace:
>       0 /CT/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
>       1 /CT/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
>       2 /CT/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException),
>   Array)
>       3 /CT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(49):
>   Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException))
>       4 /CT/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))
>       5 /CT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(79):
>   App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Ob in
>   /CT/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on
>   line 87

I have followed other's instructions to recursively call chmod 777 on the problem folder (even though it is bad practise) and still no luck.

It seems to be a fairly common problem but I can't find anything of much use.

Comment: i think this person was asking the same question like you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel

Comment: Thank you @Spycomb A combination of two of the answers on that page solved my problem. Any one else that might come across the same problem, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362459/laravel-5-permission-denied-when-writing-in-log-file/30362460#30362460) helped me.

Answer (score 7):

Short version: In addition to the **folder** needing write permission, you'll need write permission on the file itself.

```
/CT/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Try

```
chmod 777 storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Long Version: Unix permissions have, and will continue to plague, PHP developers until the end of time.

The problem is there's no simple "right" answer here.  What your permissions need to be will depend on how you're running your web-server (`mod_php` vs. fastcgi), what your current user account is, how those accounts relate (what group they're in), and how the log file was initially created.  If you first created the log file by running PHP from the command line, the file will be owned by you.  If you first created it by running PHP from the web browser, the file will be owned by the web server user.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and in-depth answer. It worked for that, but like you said it, it is now cropping up in other locations. I tried the same for this error - 
`in Filesystem.php line 81
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(/CT/storage/framework/views/5036995d8c7f7677ea6bb504d45d43fe): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/CT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', '81'`

But still it isn't working. I have checked the permissions of the file (**-rwxrwxrwx**) so I know that the chmod has worked but the error remains. Any ideas?