# The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

When I navigate to Laravel app on my CentOS server, it gives **HTTP ERROR 500**

[image]

So, when I checked my server error log, it says this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0
```

I have already set 777 permission to storage and bootstrap directories.

This very Laravel application runs fine on another server. So, what's the big deal here ?

Comment: it might be related to file permission of  SELinux, try searching for it, and try disabling SELinux first, if it is the culprit, then you need to find a way to enable SELinux while allowing your site to function properly

Comment: @am05mhz Ohh I will search for it but, that's to Greek for me since I'm kinda new to this server thing.

Comment: here for a starting line https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-temporarily-permanently-in-centos-rhel-fedora/

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975204/laravel-5-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-exception-when-connecting

Comment: you should never set permissions to 777. Try to `touch /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log` and make your php user the owner, e.g. use `chown`. Then check if it works.

Comment: Thanks all of you. Actually, the cause of the problem was SE-Linux. So, thanks again @am05mhz for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error can be fixed by disabling SE-Linux.

Check if it has been enabled by typing...

```
$ sestatus
```

So, disable it by typing...

```
# setenforce 0
```

It is said that the system needs to be restarted to to take effect the changes.

However, for me, restarting `Apache` was enough and fixed the problem :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is very bad to keep selinux off !! 
 instead use `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage` from the project directory then restart http,

Comment: just used @George method using chcon, it's more secure than disabling selinux. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is laravel and you use sail so add these lines in end of `.env` file:

```
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000
```

I know its late to answer but maybe helps for others.

Comment: Also, try stopping Docker (if using Laravel Sail), then running: `chown yourusername:yourgroup -R .` (refer to output of `ls -la` in Laravel directory for username/group), `chmod 750 -R .`, start Docker, and run `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`, and `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 22.04. If you don't want to disabling SE Linux, the solution is:
SSH into Docker container:
`docker exec -it app_name-laravel.test-1 /bin/bash`
Change the owner of storage/framework and storage/logs to `sail` not `www-data`:

```
chown -R sail:sail storage/framework
chown -R sail:sail storage/logs
```

If it still don't work, try to install htop inside that docker container. Run htop. Find the user of `/var/www/artisan serve`. Then repeat the commands above but with that user, not `sail`. Good luck!

### Update

Or better solution. Create a group for root and user from docker (mine is sail):

```
groupadd sailroot
```

then add both root and sail to the group:

```
usermod -a -G sailroot sail
usermod -a -G sailroot root
```

Change group owner of storage logs and framework to the group:

```
chown root:sailroot -R storage/framework
```

Change file permission to 775 for both:

```
chmod 775 -R storage/framework
```

In this way, you can using `php artisan serve` using php installed locally, or with docker using sail. Remember to leave the user to root, and group sailroot (or whatever you named)