# Some error with make any changes at Resources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When i`m make any changes in "resources" - the server return 500 error.
Also, if i download this folder to my PC, delete it on server and upload this folder from my PC - the server also return 500 error...

Add some logs below

Ubuntu 16.04
php 7
apache 2

```
[24-Oct-2019 14:15:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalEr in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447864/the-stream-or-file-storage-logs-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-failed-to-op)

Comment: I m fixed it only when im set permission to 777 to full /html folder. *Im was tried set permission to single folders or files with logs, its not helped. So, i think its not quite correctly, but its only 1 way, what was help me in this situation.

Comment: that's the worse you can do. Now every single file from your project will be publicly accessible.. Set just the `logs` folder to 755