# Permission denied error laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5

When i try run my laravel 5.2 application iam facing this issue

```
 ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 109:
file_put_contents(/91d1527fa409639235e4cf4fb0164907d94d4dce.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

i gave full permission to my laravel folder and storage folder.But Still facing this issue.Iam Using Ubuntu Os

Comment: Did you give at least 755 permission to that directory and does www-data is the owner of the directory?

Comment: Yes I gave 755 permission

Comment: Try to run php artisan cache:clear from the project directory, then chmod -R 777 app/storage and finally php artisan dump-autoload.

Comment: @claudios you know giving 777 permission is not good right? 755 is sufficient

Comment: @MuthaFury, yes I know. Just check if it work then try to change back to 755.

Comment: @claudios when i try to run php artisan dump-autoload,I got this issue

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "dump-autoload" is not defined

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: now dump-autoload works but still same error when i run laravel

Comment: @RexRex, Hey buddy, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362459/laravel-5-permission-denied-when-writing-in-log-file/30362460#30362460

Comment: @claudios Tried not working

Comment: dude, when the error occurs? when visiting the index page?

Comment: @Achraf Khouadja Yes

Comment: @RexRex Check my answer

Comment: Thanks you all dudes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing folder in your storage foler you have to create

make sure you have this

navigate to `storage/framework` // if you dont have the framework folder create it

and create an empty folder called `views`

Done

**Why you have the error?**
Because the app is trying to generate/create a View in a folder that does not exist

Comment: :-)   Thank you  Thank you