# file_put_contents failed to open stream permission denied in

Tags: php, android

I'm actually creating a Android application where i'm using the `volley API` to send request to a server .

My problem is while uploading an image compressed as String to the server i receive an error message from  `file_put_contents()` saying that :
**failed to open stream permission denied in**

What i did i change the permission of the directory to  777 (not safe )
but it still doing the same thing

**Im using a vps as server to test my webservice .**
here is my code :

```
$name = $allPOstVariables['imageName'];
$fileContent =  $allPOstVariables['imageFiles'];
$target_dir = "../storage/"+$name;

$decoded_images = base64_decode("$fileContent");
file_put_contents($target_dir,$decoded_images,FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Try a targer dir that is inside the script dir. Or just save to file inside the script dir.

Comment: I tried its to doing the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents(meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/file-put-contentsmeta-services-json-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)