# Installing/configurate Symfony3.2 on a Vhost Ubuntu subdomain folder --> Error 403 Forbidden and Error 500

Tags: apache, ubuntu, subdomain, vhosts, symfony-3.2

I try to install Symfony3.2 on my vhost, running Plesk under ubuntu.
My goal is to create a production-server-status to test my Symfony-projects online.
I want to get to this project using the URL `subexample.example.tld` or `subexample.example.tld/matchGen`.

On my journey through the cavern of tears and everlasting self-doubt, I saw a lot of different errors and even achieved to break the whole vhost down including my email system... great job.

Well.. now I got the error 403 Forbidden.
The good news (at least for me): I see the favicon of symfony and if I try to open the app_dev.php (`subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web/app_dev.php`) it will say `You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.`.
Opening the app.php with `subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web/app.php`result in a redirect to `subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web/` and `The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".`.
`subexample.example.tld` runs into Forbidden, too.

### I already tried/did the following:

- New Install at a different location
- PHP matchGen/bin/symfony_requirements --> [OK] Your system is ready to run Symfony projects
- Using this as Guide http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#web-server-apache-mod-php (Apache 2.4 - FastCGI)--> created my subexample.example.tld.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available, used `a2ensite subexample.example.tld.conf` and `service apache2 reload` -->  `* Reloading web server apache2`, apparently no problems.
- I tried to use a different directory for the web folder and all the other stuff --> changed nothing
- Changing the rights with `chmod` and `chown` --> well... now I know how to apply a backup... long story short --> I was way too naive and learned a valuable lesson with Ubuntu and the change of rights.
- https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-error-no-matching-directoryindex-index-html-found-solved/ --> No effect.

### Now for the error.logs:

`/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/logs/error_logs`

```
[Mon Apr 10 20:41:45.361150 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 15012] [client 87.147.219.10:5188] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 10 20:41:47.707623 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 15012] [client 87.147.219.10:5188] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

`/var/log/apache2/matchGen_error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/matchGen_access.log` are empty.

### My configfiles:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/subexample.example.tld.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subexample.example.tld
    ServerAlias www.subexample.example.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web
    <Directory  /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory  /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/matchGen_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/matchGen_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/conf/httpd.conf`

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
#IF YOU REQUIRE TO APPLY CUSTOM MODIFICATIONS, PERFORM THEM IN THE FOLLOWING FILES:
#/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/conf/vhost.conf
#/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/conf/vhost_ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

        <VirtualHost xx.xx.xxx.xxx:443 >
                ServerName "subexample.example.tld:443"
                ServerAlias "www.subexample.example.tld"
                ServerAlias "ipv4.subexample.example.tld"
                ServerAdmin "root@example.tld"
                UseCanonicalName Off

                DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld"
                CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/logs/access_ssl_log plesklog
                ErrorLog "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/logs/error_log"

                <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
                        SuexecUserGroup "xxxx" "xxxx"
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
                        UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/web_users"
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule mod_sysenv.c>
                        SetSysEnv PP_VHOST_ID "6a66d04f-d22f-4a30-bb80-ca47f117886a"
                </IfModule>

                ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/cgi-bin/"

                Alias "/plesk-stat" "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics"
                <Location  /plesk-stat/>
                        Options +Indexes
                </Location>
                <Location  /plesk-stat/logs/>
                        Require valid-user
                </Location>
                Alias /webstat /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics/webstat
                Alias /webstat-ssl /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics/webstat-ssl
                Alias /ftpstat /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics/ftpstat
                Alias /anon_ftpstat /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics/anon_ftpstat
                Alias /awstats-icon /usr/share/awstats/icon

                SSLEngine on
                SSLVerifyClient none
                SSLCertificateFile /opt/psa/var/certificates/certyKQzXqX

                SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/etc/php.ini
                SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX fastcgi

                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                        FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/etc/php.ini
                        FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX fastcgi
                        FcgidMaxRequestLen 134217728
                        FcgidIOTimeout 600
                </IfModule>

                TimeOut 600
                <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld>

                        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                                <Files ~ (\.fcgi$)>
                                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                                        Options +ExecCGI
                                </Files>
                        </IfModule>
                        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                                <Files ~ (\.php$)>
                                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                                        FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .php
                                        Options +ExecCGI
                                </Files>
                        </IfModule>

                        SSLRequireSSL

                        Options -Includes +ExecCGI

                </Directory>

                <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/web_users>

                        <IfModule mod_php4.c>
                                php_admin_flag engine off
                        </IfModule>

                        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                                php_admin_flag engine off
                        </IfModule>

                </Directory>

                <Directory /var/www/vhosts/subexample.example.tld>
                        Options +FollowSymLinks
                </Directory>

                <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics">
                        AuthType Basic
                        AuthName "Domainstatistiken"
                        AuthUserFile "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat"
                        require valid-user
                </Directory>

                <IfModule mod_security2.c>
                </IfModule>

        </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 >
        ServerName "subexample.example.tld:80"
        ServerAlias "www.subexample.example.tld"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.subexample.example.tld"
        ServerAdmin "root@example.tld"
        UseCanonicalName Off

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld"
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/logs/access_log plesklog
        ErrorLog "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/logs/error_log"

        <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
                SuexecUserGroup "xxxx" "xxxx"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
                UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/web_users"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_sysenv.c>
                SetSysEnv PP_VHOST_ID "6a66d04f-d22f-4a30-bb80-ca47f117886a"
        </IfModule>

        ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/cgi-bin/"

        Redirect permanent /plesk-stat https://subexample.example.tld/plesk-stat
        Redirect permanent /webstat https://subexample.example.tld/webstat
        Redirect permanent /webstat-ssl https://subexample.example.tld/webstat-ssl
        Redirect permanent /ftpstat https://subexample.example.tld/ftpstat
        Redirect permanent /anon_ftpstat https://subexample.example.tld/anon_ftpstat
        Redirect permanent /awstats-icon https://subexample.example.tld/awstats-icon

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                SSLEngine off
        </IfModule>

        SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/etc/php.ini
        SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX fastcgi

        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/etc/php.ini
                FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX fastcgi
                FcgidMaxRequestLen 134217728
                FcgidIOTimeout 600
        </IfModule>

        TimeOut 600
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld>

                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                        <Files ~ (\.fcgi$)>
                                SetHandler fcgid-script
                                Options +ExecCGI
                        </Files>
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                        <Files ~ (\.php$)>
                                SetHandler fcgid-script
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .php
                                Options +ExecCGI
                        </Files>
                </IfModule>

                Options -Includes +ExecCGI

        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/web_users>

                <IfModule mod_php4.c>
                        php_admin_flag engine off
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                        php_admin_flag engine off
                </IfModule>

        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/subexample.example.tld>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/statistics">
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Domainstatistiken"
                AuthUserFile "/var/www/vhosts/system/subexample.example.tld/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat"
                require valid-user
        </Directory>

        <IfModule mod_security2.c>
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Well, I think that should give you the idea of my problem.
Thank you in advance!
Ah... please explain it for dummies... I know some things... but apparently not enough.

### Edit 1:

I tried again to change the rights...
This time I created a new group, put my matchGen folder in it and tried to allow everything in this group.

```
sudo addgroup Symfony --force-badname
Allowing use of questionable username.
Adding group `Symfony' (GID 1009) ...
Done.
sudo chown root.Symfony /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen -R
chmod g+rwx /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen
```

No change.

Oh.. and I added the user www-data to the group Symfony.

### Edit 2:

I tried to work with `http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#web-server-apache-fpm`, but nothing changed.
After the reset I tried to open `subexample.example.tld/matchGen/web/` again.
Well it did not work, but this time the error seemed to be different `HTTP ERROR 500`.
So... after looking in the Looks again --> `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen/var/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/subexample.example.tld/matchGen/var/cache/prod/classes.php:8203`

It is definitely a problem with the rights. But why will it not work?
...
I tried to setup the www-data-user with acl, using this guide --> `http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd`

Instead of using var or /var at the end of the setfacl-command I used matchGen as a folder.

No change.

### Edit 3:

I did it!
This here helped me after i reached the point after Edit 2.
['Failed to open stream: Permission denied' error - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel)

1. Go in your project folder and use `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
2. Follow up with `chmod -R 777 var`
3. Finish with `composer dump-autoload`

Finally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of things you should check if you got the same problem:

- run `php bin/symfony_requirements` in your project folder. You may need to set up the timezone in your php.ini
- create and activate a config/site for your subdomain in `/etc/apache2/site-available` and use `a2ensite subexample.example.tld.conf`. Be sure to end the name with `.conf` when creating the file.
- Before you create/change the rights use `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` in your project folder, then set them for your var folder with `chmod -R 777 var`. Finish it in your project folder with `composer dump-autoload`.