# Permission denied. Laravel linux server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, permissions, server

when i try to register and send an email to the user i got this error. It was working till yesterday. From today it gives me this and i cant figure out why. 
By the way on local testing this work's. I'm stuck. Help please

```
ErrorException in compiled.php line 7512:
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/53de219dee4f11a2db4f64a2c574ad02db5613f4.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
in compiled.php line 7512
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/53de219dee4f11a2db4f64a2c574ad02db5613f4.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php', '7512', array('path' => '/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/53de219dee4f11a2db4f64a2c574ad02db5613f4.php', 'contents' => 'Please activate your account by clicking on the following link. <a href="<?php echo e(route('auth.activate', $token)); ?>"><?php echo e(route('auth.activate', $token)); ?></a> ', 'lock' => false))
at file_put_contents('/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/53de219dee4f11a2db4f64a2c574ad02db5613f4.php', 'Please activate your account by clicking on the following link. <a href="<?php echo e(route('auth.activate', $token)); ?>"><?php echo e(route('auth.activate', $token)); ?></a> ', '0') in compiled.php line 7512
at Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/53de219dee4f11a2db4f64a2c574ad02db5613f4.php', 'Please activate your account by clicking on the following link. <a href="<?php echo e(route('auth.activate', $token)); ?>"><?php echo e(route('auth.activate', $token)); ?></a> ') in compiled.php line 15769
at BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/html/resources/views/email/auth/activation.blade.php') in compiled.php line 15682
at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/resources/views/email/auth/activation.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'token' => object(ActivationToken), 'activeToken' => null, 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in compiled.php line 15517
at View->getContents() in compiled.php line 15505
at View->renderContents() in compiled.php line 15489
at View->render() in Mailer.php line 458
at Mailer->getView('email.auth.activation', array('token' => object(ActivationToken), 'activeToken' => null, 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 331
at Mailer->addContent(object(Message), 'email.auth.activation', null, null, array('token' => object(ActivationToken), 'activeToken' => null, 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message))) in Mailer.php line 205
at Mailer->send('email.auth.activation', array('token' => object(ActivationToken), 'activeToken' => null, 'connection' => null, 'queue' => null, 'delay' => null, 'message' => object(Message)), object(Closure)) in Mailable.php line 117
at Mailable->send(object(Mailer)) in Mailer.php line 192
at Mailer->send(object(SendActivationToken)) in MailableMailer.php line 99
at MailableMailer->send(object(SendActivationToken)) in SendActivationEmail.php line 30
at SendActivationEmail->handle(object(UserRegistered))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SendActivationEmail), 'handle'), array(object(UserRegistered))) in compiled.php line 10332
at Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(object(UserRegistered))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(UserRegistered))) in compiled.php line 10266
at Dispatcher->fire('App\Events\UserRegistered') in helpers.php line 480
at event(object(UserRegistered)) in AppServiceProvider.php line 25
at AppServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(object(User))
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(User))) in compiled.php line 10266
at Dispatcher->fire('eloquent.created: App\User', array(object(User))) in compiled.php line 11029
at Model->fireModelEvent('eloquent.created: App\User', false) in compiled.php line 10996
at Model->performInsert(object(Builder)) in compiled.php line 10941
at Model->save() in compiled.php line 10599
at Model::create(array('name' => 'Alessandro Mazari', 'surname' => 'Mazari', 'email' => 'alessandro.mazzari.v.l@gmail.com', 'password' => '$2y$10$R/lwIQ5.dgNgArYE3AuyGeDSyUWoILtnT2LvrDGNjV9aDevj9/Xnq', 'hidden_profile' => 'off', 'faction' => 'soon', 'mac_address_handlebar' => '', 'active' => false)) in RegisterController.php line 76
at RegisterController->create(array('_token' => 'Jeh3Amk6XGHDiFz5fqYyBIGYGblbNlZxwzM9r4lJ', 'name' => 'Alessandro Mazari', 'surname' => 'Mazari', 'email' => 'alessandro.mazzari.v.l@gmail.com', 'password' => 'alessa', 'password_confirmation' => 'alessa', 'faction' => 'soon', 'mac_address_handlebar' => '', 'hidden_profile' => 'off')) in compiled.php line 2695
at RegisterController->register(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RegisterController), 'register'), array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 9584
at Controller->callAction('register', array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 9611
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(RegisterController), 'register') in compiled.php line 8665
at Route->runController() in compiled.php line 8646
at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8355
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10177
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3312
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13749
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12155
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13495
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13432
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10054
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8356
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8347
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8338
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2575
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3374
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10069
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10054
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2519
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2503
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: check folder permissions.

Comment: its saying *failed to open stream: Permission denied*

Comment: It looks like the process has not enough permissions on that specific view file (`/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/53de219dee4f11a2db4f64a2c574ad02db5613f4.php`).  Please check that is does.

Comment: The user executing the application must have read/write permissions to the `/var/www/html/storage/framework/views/` directory

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot comment because I have joined stackoverflow recently and I do not have enough credits so I post an answer.

Laravel needs write permission to storage folder ( and Just this folder). so please run:

```
sudo chmod -R 7777 storage
```

I hope I have helped,
regards,

Comment: But why do i need this from now? It worked fine tilt yesterday without this

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: You are so welcome. It seems that the folder privileges reinstated. So you need to give write access to laravel for this folder. If the answer was helpful, please accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see something like `failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache` you should remind yourself that Laravel needs to have write permissions to specific directories.

`sudo chmod 777 dir_name` is your friend here :)

Quoting the docs:

> Directory Permissions
>
> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions.
>   Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories
>   should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.