# readfile(): failed to open stream: Permission denied on Windows Server IIS 8

Tags: php, iis, permissions

I've made a file manager application
I have an issue when I'm trying to download files 
The files that are inside the uploads directory and have moved from my php temp directory dont inherit the folder permission so I got this error in php error log

```
PHP Warning:  readfile(files/xxx.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...
```

When I go inside IIS and go into the security tab and apply inherit permissions it works

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2147483648');

    $file = "files/".htmlspecialchars($_GET["file"]);

    $quoted = sprintf('"%s"',addcslashes(basename($file),'"\\"'));
    $size   = filesize($file);
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

        header("Content-Type: force-download");

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$quoted);

        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
    } else {
        header("Location: fileNotFound.php?file=$file");
    }
```

Comment: Check  permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Failed to open stream: Permission denied' error - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23540083/6521116)

Comment: did you change your permission to that directory?

Comment: Yup all permissions checked. But the new files that are uploaded are not inherit both IIS user and IIS_IUSRS permissions only the IIS

Answer (score 0):

Mmm if you can change folder permission, you can solve the problem. Maybe you also need to restart IIS.

Well, you are using `ob_clean` that works when you discards content of output buffer. Anyway, if you use `ob_clean` content before call the function you can get that error. So, ... it is possible that you leaved some " " space or other "invisible" character in other php files?

Comment: I've restarted IIS, I've already checked all the folder permissions but no luck. I also gave same permissions as my temp folder

Comment: Try to pass the full file path like "c:/foo/bar" instead of relative path

Comment: If php is installed as a service, you need to restart also php.

Comment: Not working even with full path 
Also have restarted php

Comment: You are using windows, ... try with restart the OS. And try also to paste more code here.