# Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Laravel 5.4 Even Al File Permission are granted to the path using Store Function in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload a file into C:\Users\sandeep\maxo\storage\app\public folder in laravel 5.4. I am using the below code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form  action="{{ URL::to('importExcelFile') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="import_file" />
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <br/>
                <button >Import CSV or Excel File</button>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

$path = $request->file('import_file')->store('public');

is the laravel code.

But I am getting an error like this

> fopen(C:\Users\sandeep\maxo\storage\app\public/K4oIHMXveyx2VChmAXAcNkTmoIXKACvqoIbbHCeB.): failed to open stream: Permission denied

This is the  picture of my error 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLPOA.png)

But When i Upload the image its working fine

Comment: try this command to link storage directory to public php artisan storage:link

Comment: no change in the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Failed to open stream: Permission denied' error - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel)

Comment: i already checked this link,all file permissions are granted and i am using windows

Comment: image file is updated but getting this error for Excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on terminal **sudo chmod -R 777 public** it will change the directory permission

Comment: never ever set 777 permission on any folder to avoid being hacked. thats been discussed here 100500 times.

Answer (score 5):

As has been stated everywhere, you better not give `777` permissions, its a security risk. Instead just use

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage

if you are using apache, it will give permission to the apache's user